# Android activity version

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk, version

I have an android project that supports android 2.3.3.

But is supports sdk version 17 as well.
When I create a new activity it creates an activity specific for version 17.

How can I make a correct activity that works for both SDK 10 and 17?

I've already added the following:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Activity that works for.."? Activity class is available from SDK version 1 and above, but certain methods can become available only since specific versions. If you're not using those methods, you don't need to worry.

Comment: What do you mean by `specific for version 17`? Does it work in earlier versions?

Comment: I haven't tried it with lower versions yet but when I compare the last created activity with older ones the layout is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should specify minSdk version to 10 and targetSdk to 17.
It means that your code will compile under sdk version 17 to prevent reflection of some code

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

And your question is not about API dependence. It is about styling. If you want to make your activities look simillar on every android version since 2.1 you should use HoloEverywhere library
https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Comment: what means different layout? Do you specify theme for activity?

Comment: I added: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  this fixed the styling problem on the phone but eclipse is still showing a different layout.

Comment: @JasperFioole, in eclipse graphic view you should specify theme which will use to render this layout in top bar

Comment: Thx, I think I'm fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Really all you need is to add `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />` in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest set the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` accordingly. As far as I know you can onyl set this for the whole application, no for individual activities.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create your new project that time  you set min and max SDK version. Your application will work perfectly on min to max version perfectly. You can set your target version and change it afterwords. This target version means your testing device version.

Comment: setting maxSDK is very bad practice

Comment: my mistake.
set min and targetsdkversion

Comment: I only defined min and target.

Answer (score 0):

In your code are you using some api or some method which are not supported in platform 10 but it supported in 17 ?? Have you used any kind of this code`@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")`